# Double category axis, each with its own color

Tags: amcharts

Say I have a category axis with years 2010-2020. Is it possible with AmCharts to have the first part (2010-2015) of the category axis in one color, and the other part (2016-2020) in another color? Or have two sequential axis, each with its own color?

Alternatively I could use two guides to get the same effect, but I can't get that to work either. It seems like a guide can't have both a value/toValue and a category/toCategory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regular Serial chart does not support multiple category axes. You can have multi-line category axis labels, but you can't color them separately.

To insert a break in a category axis label, use `\n` symbol in a category string. (provided you are using non-date-based category axis). I.e.:

```
{
  "category": "2010\n2016",
  "value1": 100,
  "value2": 120
}
```

Here's an example of such usage:

http://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/42f02ece6ae31376275407437afe4f05

---

Another solution, like you pointed out, is to use guides. You can add some custom code to automatically create a guide for each category, like it is implemented in this example:

http://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/7a95aa85ea3871248a189d849a7cf967

---

And finally, if you could consider using XY chart, rather than Serial, you could have multiple horizontal value axes, that can be colored differently and made date-based:

http://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/412ad4fbf743be05e154ad4321994699